# How to add previous/next buttons instead of >/< signs in pagination area of category page in opencart?

Tags: php, pagination, opencart

I want to add buttons that say "Next" and "Previous" instead of >/< signs in my category page in the pagination area. I believe this would ease the browsing through pages for customers of all ages.

In the template file for category page I only get "echo $pagination;" and when I went to controller file for category page it did not make much sense to me (I am not a hardcore php programmer) and from what I understood the references for text leaded to language file and I checked out language files for category.php and english.php yet I was not able to find the >/< signs anywhere.

I have been looking for answers everywhere but I haven't been able to find any solution for this.. not even a module.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Ctrl-F`, `">`, `Enter`

Comment: This question is opencart specific and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple mate, just open the following file in your editor and change the variables according to your needs:

```
opencart/system/library/pagination.php
```

You'll find following variables there:

```
public $total = 0;
public $page = 1;
public $limit = 20;
public $num_links = 10;
public $url = '';
public $text = 'Showing {start} to {end} of {total} ({pages} Pages)';
public $text_first = '|&lt;';
public $text_last = '&gt;|';
public $text_next = '&gt;';
public $text_prev = '&lt;';
public $style_links = 'links';
public $style_results = 'results';
```

Just replace

```
public $text_next = '&gt;';
```

with

```
public $text_next = 'Next';
```

and

```
public $text_prev = '&lt;';
```

with

```
public $text_prev = 'Previous';
```

Hope it helps :)